# How to use TypedDataHash to make a transaction?

Tags: ethereumjs, signature, ecdsa, meta-transactions

I am trying to make a Meta Transaction without using the conventional TypedData object.
Instead I have used `ethers.utils._TypedDataEncoder.hash` to create the hash.

I signed the hash using the `ethereumjs-util` and `eth-sig-util` packages but want a different approach to create the signature.

Now I am not sure how to use the hash without using the `ethereumjs-util` and `eth-sig-util` packages but rather the signer created using the private key (`const walletSigner = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider)`).

```
const signature = await walletSigner.sign(hash)
```

Something like the above which will create a valid signature.

Please let me know if the hash can be signed using the web3.js Javascript Ethereum API.

Answer (score 0):

for meta transaction you have 3 steps :

1-Implement the signature function in your smart contract and pass your values to it. it use "_hashTypedDataV4" and "keccak256",  like below:

```
function hashGenerator(YourStruct memory yourStruct)
    internal
    view
    returns (bytes32)
{
    return
        _hashTypedDataV4(
            keccak256(
                abi.encode(
                    keccak256(
                        "YourStruct(address x,uint256 y)"
                    ),
                    yourStruct.x//x value 
                    yourStruct.y//y value
                    
                )
            )
        );
}
```

2-in web3 you must do the same in sign values, like this

```
 const signature = await signer._signTypedData(
  // Domain
  {
    name: "nameOfYourContract",
    version: "1.0",//your version
    chainId: yourchainID,
    verifyingContract: this.yourContract,
  },
  // Types
  {
    YourStruct: [
      { name: "x", type: "address" },
      { name: "y", type: "uint256" },
    ],
  },
  // Values
  {
   x_value,
   y_value
  } //
);
```

3-in the last step you have to compare web3 signature with your smart contract signature to prove it.

```
  function signVerify(
    YourStruct memory yourStruct,
    bytes calldata signature
) internal view returns (address) {
    bytes32 digest = hashGenerator(yourStruct);
    return ECDSAUpgradeable.recover(digest, signature);
}
```

**for better understanding**, **I recommend to** [read this link](https://soliditydeveloper.com/meta-transactions).